# How to pull a variable out of a string I need to compare to another, pre-existing string c#

Tags: c#, string-comparison, rule-engine, validationrules

I have a rules engine that takes a string as a name of a rule, and compares it to a string, predicate dictionary. I'm writing a rule that will compare two datetimes and return true if they match, but allow a windows of a configurable number of seconds. Ideally, I'd like for my string/predicate key value pair to look something like

```
{"Allow <x> seconds", AllowXSeconds}
```

A user applying the rule would decide they would like a 10 second window on either side of the original datetime so they would say "Allow 10 seconds" in config. I want my code to be able to to recognize that the user wants to apply the "Allow  seconds" rule, then pull the "10" out so I can use it as a variable in the rule's logic. I'd rather not use regex, as the class is already built, and I don't know if I'll be allowed to refactor it in that way. I will, though, if no one has any clever ideas on how to do this. Thanks in advance, to all you smart guys and gals!

Comment: Do you only need to parse the value, or also validate the format?

Comment: If I understand what you're asking, I think I need to validate the format as well. The rules engine needs to know that the string "Allow 10 seconds" is connected to the AllowXSeconds method.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate using [`string.StartsWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baketfxw(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`string.EndsWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.endswith(v=vs.110).aspx) then use [`string.Substring`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the desired value and [`int.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) to attempt to parse the value and validate that it is an integer

```
string str = "Allow 10 seconds";
int result;
if (str.StartsWith("Allow ") 
    && str.EndsWith(" seconds") 
    && int.TryParse(str.Substring(6, str.Length - 14), out result))
{
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid");
}
```

Also if desired there are overloads of `StartsWith` and `EndsWith` that will allow for case insensitive matching as well.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a perfect candidate for regular expressions.

Here is a [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) program that demonstrates:

```
void Main()
{
    var lines = new[]
    {
        "Allow 10 seconds",
        "Allow 5 seconds",
        "Use 5mb"
    };

    var rules = new Rule[]
    {
        new Rule(
            @"^Allow\s+(?<seconds>\d+)\s+seconds?$",
            ma => AllowSeconds(int.Parse(ma.Groups["seconds"].Value)))
    };

    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        bool wasMatched = rules.Any(rule => rule.Visit(line));
        if (!wasMatched)
            Console.WriteLine($"not matched: {line}");
    }
}

public void AllowSeconds(int seconds)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"allow: {seconds} second(s)");
}

public class Rule
{
    public Rule(string pattern, Action<Match> action)
    {
        Pattern = pattern;
        Action = action;
    }

    public string Pattern { get; }
    public Action<Match> Action { get; }

    public bool Visit(string line)
    {
        var match = Regex.Match(line, Pattern);
        if (match.Success)
            Action(match);
        return match.Success;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
allow: 10 second(s)
allow: 5 second(s)
not matched: Use 5mb
```